# I cant remove "hiss" sound on my Audacity track

Tags: audio, audacity, volume, hiss

To briefly explain my problem, when I play the audio track on Audacity and any media player on my PC, it sounds absolutely perfect. When I try on my phone's media player, it also sounds perfect. But when I implement in a games files as a soundtrack, it sounds HORRIBLE. Lowering the project rate hz reduces the hiss sound, but the sound quality reduces as well.

I have tried:

- Equalizing.
- Low pass filtering.
- dB volume lowering.
- Changing frequency rate and resampling rate.

Noise reduction didn't work also (probably cause Audacity and other media players don't detect that hiss sound).

NONE OF THE ABOVE HAVE WORKED FOR ME.

P.S.: The track I am trying to fix is downloaded music.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please attach an image or clip for reference? is the format mp4 or wav? This question is very broad.

One thing I can think of is that the sound is far too loud. When music is exported at a volume louder than 0db it will start "Clipping". When sound clips, a distorted hissing noise occurs. This may not be noticeable in your DAW of choice, however, as soon as a sound is compressed this distortion immediately becomes obvious.

It could be an encoding problem on the game engine's end. Maybe you are loading the wrong kind of file into the game and it doesn't know how to properly process it. This could lead to artifacts in the output.

Again, because we have not been given much material to go off of, it makes it difficult for us to help you.